# code works in command input prompt but not in script R

Tags: r, read.table

I am trying to read a file my code is simply:

```
df   = read.table("DF",header=FALSE)
```

I am doing this for df1, df2, df3, etc. But for some reason I reach an error at df. It is more 7x as long as some of the other files if that makes any difference.

the error i get is:

```
> debugSource('script.R')
Called from: eval(expr, p)
Browse[1]> n
debug at //location/to/file/script.R#13: df = read.table("DF",header=FALSE)
Browse[2]>
```

df   = read.table("DF",header=FALSE) works perfectly find in the command input line, but can anyone explain why I can't get it to run in the script?

Comment: It may be that the working directory may be different for the two environments.  Try specifying the full path to DF

Comment: I fixed the issue by putting that line on top so that it is run first.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.